# Dissolve transition (alpha animation) only works in fade in and not in fade out

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialog

I am animating a Dialog to have some effects when being opened.
I have it implemented in an OnClickListener like this:

```
final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(DetailActivity.this,
                        R.style.FullscreenDialogTheme);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                nagDialog.setCancelable(true);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_image);
                PhotoView ivPreview = (PhotoView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_preview_image);
                ivPreview.setImageBitmap(mWallpaperBitmap);
                nagDialog.show();
```

with this style:

```
<style name="FullscreenDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyAnimation.Window</item>
</style>
<style name="MyAnimation.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/anim_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/anim_out</item>
</style>
```

Using this animations:

**anim_in**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:startOffset="150"
    android:duration="200"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY = "30%"
    />
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:duration="300"
    />
<alpha
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

**anim_out**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="150"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY = "30%"
    />
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="200"
    />
<alpha
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

Unluckly only the alpha animation shows correctly only when I open the Dialog, when I close it the `translate` and `scale` animation work as intended but there is no alpha fading. Thanks.